# Error during testing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I am trying to run a unit test.

The test needs to have `require_relative 'francis'`

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'francis'

class FrancisTest < MiniTest::Test
```

When I try running `rake test TEST=test/francis_test.rb` I get an error of

```
(in C:/Users/chris2/Documents/RailsProjects/francis)
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- C:/Users/chris2/Documents/RailsProjects/francis/test/francis
C:/Users/chris2/Documents/RailsProjects/francis/test/francis_test.rb:2:in `require_relative'
C:/Users/chris2/Documents/RailsProjects/francis/test/francis_test.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:single
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How can I run this test?

---

Update

I moved francis_test.rb to the root of the project. I also remarked out the require_relative statement., I also had to change the setup line to `@teen = ::Franci.new` instead of Francis.new

So the beginning of francis_test looks like

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
# require_relative 'franci'
require 'test_helper'

class FrancisTest < MiniTest::Test
  attr_reader :teen

  def setup
    @teen = ::Franci.new
  end

  def test_stating
    assert_equal 'Whatevs.', teen.yo('Oh blah di, oh blah da.')
  end

  def test_yelling
    assert_equal 'Chill!', teen.yo('GOOOAAAALLL!')
  end
```

I seem to need require 'test_helper'.

BTW - my ruby and rails versions are

```
Rails 4.2.5.1
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]
```

Now if I run `rake test TEST=francis_test.rb -v`

I see  (partial)

```
# Running:

FrancisTest#test_stating_with_acronyms = 0.01 s = E
FrancisTest#test_inquiring = 0.00 s = E
FrancisTest#test_question_with_just_numbers = 0.00 s = E
. . . 

Finished in 0.013518s, 1257.5400 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.


  1) Error:
FrancisTest#test_stating_with_acronyms:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

  2) Error:
FrancisTest#test_inquiring:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

A couple of questions

1. is attr_reader valid in Ruby 2.2.4? I looked at the API but couldn't quite make sense of it.
2. Why am I getting 'wrong number of arguments'? I haven't used the attr_reader but it seems that when calling it the way I am, it should be passing the argument to teen.yo.

BTW - the francis table only has one column - 'yo'.

Comment: Are you sure the francis_test file is right under the test folder?

Answer (score 0):

`require_relative` complements the builtin method require by allowing you to load a file that is relative to the file containing the `require_relative` statement.

For example, if you have unit test classes in the "test" directory, and data for them under the test "test/data" directory, then you might use a line like this in a test case:

```
require_relative "data/customer_data_1"
```

Answer (score 0):

> is attr_reader valid in Ruby 2.2.4? I looked at the API but couldn't
>   quite make sense of it.

[Yes, it is](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader). However you don't need it because columns are automatically made available as attributes by ActiveRecord.

> Why am I getting 'wrong number of arguments'? I haven't used the
>   attr_reader but it seems that when calling it the way I am, it should
>   be passing the argument to teen.yo.

To answer this question, I need the content of your `francis.rb` file.